# Grails Plugin: Jasper plugin - No such report spec error

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

I am getting an error when trying to run any of the demo reports in the Grails Jasper Plugin demo page.  I'm thinking I'm missing some configuration, but the plugin doc doesn't give any more detail.

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/testGrailsProject01/jasper/
Class
java.lang.Exception
Message
No such report spec: /reports\sample-jasper-plugin (jasper or .jrxml)
Around line 195 of PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
192:            if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(cacheOperations)) {
193:                log.debug("No cacheable annotation found for {}:{} {}",
194:                        new Object[] { request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI(), getContext() });
195:                chain.doFilter(request, response);
196:                return;
197:            }
198:
Around line 63 of AbstractFilter.java
60:     try {
61:         // NO_FILTER set for RequestDispatcher forwards to avoid double gzipping
62:         if (filterNotDisabled(request)) {
63:             doFilter(request, response, chain);
64:         }
65:         else {
66:             chain.doFilter(req, res);
Trace
   Line | Method
->> 195 | doFilter in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    63 | doFilter in AbstractFilter.java
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: I have added the reports folder to my project, but haven't added any reports yet.  I'm assuming the demo will have their own reports?  

The default location for your report templates is web-app/reports in your project directory. Here you can place your *.jasper or *.jrxml (jrxml files will be compiled automatically by the plugin).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the plugin doesn't provide a report at all, at least I can't find any.  You will need to create a basic test report in Jasper and then place it within your /reports/ folder.